# In this case, how should I run docker?

Tags: docker

I downloaded a docker image from the official website. I mounted my files. The only function of this docker environment is to compile an executable file. But if I regenerate a container every time, I have to download a lot of things every time I compile.

Is there any way to create a container, every time I need to compile, use it, and close it after compiling. Those dependent files are only downloaded once?

Is there such a possibility. I write a script that runs. Every time I don't need to enter the container, I directly let the container execute the script, and I can see its output outside, because some errors may be reported when compiling.

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I voted that this needs more clarity, no idea if it's a duplicate. I'd like to see a [mcve].

Comment: What you describe seems to be the normal way Docker works – you `docker pull` the image so it exists locally and you don't have to re-download its contents, then `docker run` a container to run its process, and it will by default print its logs to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

`Is there any way to create a container, every time I need to compile, use it, and close it after compiling. Those dependent files are only downloaded once?`

You can save such common image and reuse it with [--cache-from flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specifying-external-cache-sources).

`...I write a script that runs... let the container execute the script...`

You bind mount a volume that contain your script, and a volume that your script will save the output. Example:

`docker run -v <local path for script>:<path in container eg. docker-entrypoint.sh> -v <local path to output directory>:<path in container where your compilation will save the output> ...`

Upon run completed you will find your files in the output directory.